# Are there any colors that should not be used in UI design?

Tags: color

Are there any colors that should not be used in UI design? Which one(s)? Why?

Comment: Blue. And yellow.  And Green.

Comment: Also, songs shouldn't use g, f, or b#

Comment: Avoid #000666 as it is the color of the beast (and just to be on the safe side, don't use #00029A either.)

Comment: WAY too generic of a question.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There are no colours that shouldn't be used, but there are combinations that aren't helpful in terms of aesthetic and in ease of perception, or inappropriate use of colour that clashes with culturally accepted symbols.

Don't forget to check that the colour blind will not have difficulty with your UI, and that the use of colour to encode information is only done so redundantly (if you take the colour away people can still use the UI easily).

I recommend *[Ware's Visual Thinking for Design](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/3239938-visual-thinking-for-design)* as a good book that covers a decent amount of colour theory and its application.

As a handy shortcut to spot many problems, take a look at your UI in greyscale (and/or carry out initial design without colour) and see if there are any colour-use problems with your UI.

Comment: And keep in mind that not everyone who is colour blind is red-green - some of us are yellow-green aflicted.

Comment: There are apps that let you generate color schemes, and apply different kinds of colorblindness (protanopy, deuteranomaly, etc) to see how it effectively "looks" and contrasts to people with that condition.  Here's one: http://colorschemedesigner.com/